# SQL query in View Model of MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have the following scalar valued SQL Server function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Share] 
    (@date1 datetime, 
     @date2 nvarchar(max), 
     @date3 nvarchar(max) )
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @date2_ datetime = CAST(@date2 AS datetime)
    DECLARE @date3_ datetime = CAST(@date3 AS datetime)

    RETURN (SELECT
                CASE
                    WHEN (@date1 < @date3_ AND @date2_ >= @date3_) OR
                         (@date2_ < @date3_ AND @date1 >= @date3_)
                       THEN 1
                       ELSE 0 
                END)
END
```

And the following viewmodel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connString = @"Server =.\SQL2K17; Database = SampleDB; Trusted_Connection = True;"; 

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
                {
                    string query = @"SELECT dbo.udf_Share(@date1, @date2, @date3); ";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date1", "01/01/2016"));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date2", "01/01/2021"));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date3", "01/10/2019"));
                    conn.Open();
                    var objectResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    int Result = Convert.ToInt32(objectResult);
                    Console.WriteLine(Result.ToString());
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Connection in getting established but i am not able to use the function. Maybe i am not passing the params properly. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have syntax error in the first line. You are sending '@effdate2', but requesting '@date2'.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql function should be like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Share] (@date1 nvarchar(max), @date2 nvarchar(max), @date3 nvarchar(max) )
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
declare @date1_ datetime=cast(@date1 as datetime)
declare @date2_ datetime=cast(@date2 as datetime)
declare @date3_ datetime=cast(@date3 as datetime)
  RETURN (SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN (@date1_ < @date3_ AND @date2_ >= @date3_) OR
           (@date2_ < @date3_ AND @date1_ >= @date3_)
       THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END)
END
```

Comment: Edited. Thanks! But the issue is different.

Comment: @edith Edited my answer. Please try this.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `@date1` is required as `DateTime`. Instead, you pass it as `string`. Either modify the function and make it `nvarchar` like the others, or do this:

```
SqlParameter parameter1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@date1", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
parameter1.Value = _your_datetime_value_;
```

Comment: You can also do AddWithValue() to shorten this by one line per parameter. DateTime.Parse() would also set the date up correctly from your string.